# OCaml functor taking polymorphic variant type

Tags: ocaml

Trying to compile

```
module F (M : sig
  type t = [> `Foo ]
end) = struct
  type t = [ M.t | `Bar ]
end
```

gets me

```
Error: A type variable is unbound in this type declaration.
In type [> `Foo ] as 'a the variable 'a is unbound
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`` type t = [> `Foo] `` is invalid since `` [> `Foo] `` is an open type and contains a type variable implicitly. The definition is rejected just as the following type definition is rejected since the RHS has a type variable which is not quantified in LHS:

```
type t = 'a list
```

You have to make it closed:

```
type t = [ `Foo ]
```

or quantify the type variable:

```
type 'a t = [> `Foo] as 'a
```

which is equivalent to

```
type 'a t = 'a constraint 'a = [> `Foo]
```

Comment: I would like my functor argument `M` to be able to extend `F.t` with additional variants not specified in the signature; e.g. `type t = [ \`Foo | \`Baz]`. So I don't think a closed type will work. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Also, I'm not clear as to why the open type contains a type variable -- could you explain / link to an explanation? RWO doesn't seem to mention anything about implicit type variables.

Comment: ``type t = [> `Baz | M.t]`` is what you want; here `M.t` can be closed.

Comment: Please note that "implicit type variables" I used is not an official OCaml word. In OCaml everything instantiable must have type variables, including open polyvariant types ``[> `A | `B]`` and open object types `<m:int; ..>`. But you can omit writing them if you do not use them elsewhere. They are actually short ways to write type variables with constraints: ``'a constraint 'a = [> `A | `B]`` and `'a constraint as 'a = <m:t; ..>`.  They are instantiable only to subtypes of their constraints.  (You can also write equivalent like ``[> `A | `B] as 'a`` and `<m:int; ..> as 'a`.)

Comment: Follow-up, let me know if you'd prefer me to make a new question: I want `M.t` to extend `t`, so I don't want `M.t` to be closed... is that even possible?

Comment: I am afraid not. `M.t` seems to be closed if you want to write ``[> `A | M.t]``. BTW, I think you need not to define `M.t` as opened, since make an opened poly variant type from a closed one is pretty easy like `[> M.t]`.

Comment: Is there material that explains how exactly ``[> `A | `B]`` being an abbreviation for ``'a constraint 'a = [> `A | `B]`` works, especially when it interacts with closed types?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```ml
module F ( M : sig
  type base_t = [ `Foo ]
  type 'a t = [> base_t] as 'a
end) = struct
  type t = [ M.base_t | `Bar ] M.t
end
```

`M.base_t` is closed, while `M.t('a)` is polymorphic. `F` constructs `M.t` using `M.base_t` extended with `'Bar`.

Here is [reasonml try link](https://reasonml.github.io/try?rrjsx=true&reason=LYewJgrgNgpgBAMTgXjgCgLIC44G8BQcRxJJALgJ4AO8ARgIYDOMA+mSnANpwA+cABghAgAugG5CpKUUo04ZNAHJ6ASg6cAfHAbM2IuEzjKJ00gF81yLQRnV47VBgB0C7s52t2ffgCF6AJxEVCTMJIA), which includes the snippet above both in OCaml and ReasonML syntax, and proves that it compiles.